# Using local modules Python without installation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to pack an application written in Python.

- I can't use PyInstaller because I can't have a .exe or anything like that, I need pure python scripts being executed (I have Popen in my code calling some of my scripts and passing parameters);
- I need it to work cross-plataform (I KNOW that to do so, I need to generate the package in each system because a package generated on Linux won't work in a Mac and vice-versa);

Since I can't really pack it, my idea is to have a folder called modules and have all the dependencies inside it, then, in my code I would just point the imports to this folder. I would zip the entire project and ship it, the user would just unpack and run it.
The problem is:

- How to not only download the package in a specific folder but also install it there? (I can't alter my user's environment, this is a MUST);
- How to direct my imports to this local folder? I think I can do something like `import modules.numpy` for example, but then, numpy have dependencies of its own... how to make sure it will look into my custom folder?

My scenario:

- I have a requirements.txt for my project; I have several local files that are used inside the project; I have a Popen that calls one of my file.py; I am using Python3;
- I can't use virtualenv because I am using wxPython and there's a conflict between it and virtualenv (no idea why - something related with main thread...)

Comment: Firstly, you should fix whatever your "conflict" is (perhaps ask about that in a separate question). Secondly, you should question why you are running Python scripts from other Python scripts via Popen rather than importing them and calling them directly.

Comment: Have you thought about distributing with docker?  With docker for Mac and docker for Windows you can run Linux containers on all the most common operating systems, and it will provide a lot more isolation between components than merely vending dependencies.  It also alleviates the need for separate distributions, especially if your code isn't pure Python

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi, well, there is a thread about the wxPython not working in a virtualenv (is a known issue) but even with the fix, I couldn't make it work. I have a deadline, I asked the question, I invested a lot of time trying to fix it. I couldn't so, I am trying through another path :)

Comment: @DanielRoseman The Popen is required to manage any possible error that crashes my application in a way that I really can't manage with try/except. This is required for my scenario.

Comment: @DanFarrell Yes, I thought about that, but my application need access to the running process in the machine, I will try to test it... but I don't know if docker will provide the access I need to the main OS...

Comment: Not an answer, just an aside: you can always use `Popen` to launch a packed executable of your application. One project I worked on years ago checked `sys.executable` to determine if it was bundled or not, and constructed a command line accordingly.

Comment: @DanielPryden but how would this work? Like, I have a main.py that calls wrapper.py. I could change the `Popen` call to use the `.exe` instead of `.py`, but in my case, I have parameters being passed... can I pass parameters to a `.exe` with `Popen`?

Comment: I would have the main program take a special command-line argument (or, possibly, check for a special environment variable) to indicate that it is the child process. Then the outer process simply calls itself again with the flag to indicate that the new process is the child.

Comment: And yes, you can pass arbitrary command line arguments with `Popen`. Read the documentation on the `subprocess` module for the details, or feel free to ask that as a separate question on Stack Overflow

Comment: @DanielPryden I know I can pass command line arguments.. but for an executable???

Comment: @DanFarrell I tried with docker but I couldn't make it work... I need data from the main system and the docker can't provide me that

Comment: You certainly can’t `import modules.numpy`: other existing code must be able to `import numpy`.